# Efficient way to fetch_array from n column

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, mysqli

Say I have a table as follow:

```
+---------+------+------+---+-----+---+
| term    | 1    | 2    | 3 | ... | n |
+---------+------+------+---+-----+---+
| connect | 7    | 14   | 2 | ... | 8 |
| finish  | 1    | NULL | 9 | ... | 1 |
| ...     | ...  | ...  | . | ... | . |
| net     | NULL | 6    | 1 | ... | 5 |
+---------+------+------+---+-----+---+
```

`*the header means document name, while the value bellow means frequency of the term occurrence in the document

I need to select the row for specific `term` value. Currently I use:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `term_doc` WHERE `term`='$term'");

while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){

    $result_[] = $row;

}
```

From the above script I get:

```
Array ([0]=>Array([0]=>connect*
                  [term]=>connect*
                  [1]=>7
                  [2]=>14
                  [3]=>3
                  ...
                  [n]=>8)...)
```

Elements with asterisk are undesirable. To get clean array I need to apply the following script

```
$doc_with_term = $result_[0];

unset($doc_with_term[0]);

unset($doc_with_term['term']);
```

So I get the following array:

```
Array([1]=>7
      [2]=>14
      [3]=>3
      ...
      [n]=>8)
```

I want to know if there are some elegant ways to fetch the query result without the last script to get clean array

Comment: You may have noticed that MySQLi has the ability to use [prepared statement and variable binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), so you don't have to stuff everything into your SQL statement.

Comment: I'm sorry for double `FROM`. I haven't used prepared statement before thanks for the link. I'll read it.

Answer (score 0):

You want your array not to include the field "term"? Easiest way to do that:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM FROM `term_doc` WHERE `term`='$term'");

$doc_with_term = $result->fetch_assoc();

unset($doc_with_term['term']);
```

If you don't want to use the unset-function you have to specify which fields you want in your query, for example

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT `1`,`2`,`3` FROM FROM `term_doc` WHERE `term`='$term'");

$doc_with_term = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

**EDIT**

I still don't get why you want this. There is no way to exclude fields from your result, only to include them.

You may use

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE
```

to get a list of your fields and use them in your SELECT afterwards, but that seems to be a lot of effort for something that's way (!) easier with unset().

Comment: _“You want your array not to include the field "term"?”_ – no, I think he does not want the _column_ `term` to show up in his result array, despite using `SELECT *`.

Comment: I want all column except `term`, but I wan't specify the columns in query because I have more than a hundred columns. Type it one by one is not applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Just design your database properly.

It seems you need a table where this row is represented as a column:

```
term_id | value
      1 |     7
      1 |    14
      1 |     2
      2 |     1
      2 |     9
```

and so on.

this way you will have your fields with simple regular query. Using [good mysql abstraction library](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) it will be just one line of code:

```
$sql    = "SELECT value FROM terms, term_doc WHERE term=?s AND term_id=id";
$result = $db->getCol($sql, $term);
```

note the placeholder usage that makes your query safe

Comment: No, he wants _all_ of his `1` to `n` columns, but without the column `term` that `SELECT *` of course delivers as well.

Comment: I think if I transpose my database I will have more simple query `SELECT $term FROM term_doc` while `$term` is specific term I want to query

Comment: After talking to my friend, I decide to redesign my database. Although working with matrix, I needn't to make my database similar to the matrix. Thank you for your advice.